# Is it possible to execute an ansible playbook from a URL?

Tags: ansible

I'd love to be able to run `ansible-playbook -i <inventory_url> <playbook_url>` from my machine, but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ansible itself doesn't let you do this.  But [Ansible Tower](http://www.ansible.com/tower) (a commercial product of theirs) does allow you to perform all sorts of Ansible-related tasks, including running playbooks, etc. through a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) interface.

Comment: You can also wrap Ansible inside a system like Rundeck and use that API to trigger Ansible jobs. Rundeck is free if that helps any  ;)

Answer (score 1):

**No**. [You can see the source code here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/bin/ansible-playbook#L162), which shows the playbooks are assumed to be local:

```
if not os.path.exists(playbook):
    raise errors.AnsibleError("the playbook: %s could not be found" % playbook)
if not (os.path.isfile(playbook) or stat.S_ISFIFO(os.stat(playbook).st_mode)):
        raise errors.AnsibleError("the playbook: %s does not appear to be a file" % playbook)
```

[Here's the documentation on Python's `os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html), showing that is meant for local files.